# How can I read an IMAP account via Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap

Is it possible to read an IMAP email address via my Gmail account?

According to [the docs I have found](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21289) they only seem to support reading of POP3, but I find that a bit weird?

Comment: You're not the only one who wants that. Way back when Google launched IMAP to access Gmail people have been clamoring to have Gmail as an IMAP client. Like this one: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/10/gmail-supports-imap.html?showComment=1193236320000#c5986040157486253100

Comment: Is this for a one-time import, or for continuous sync?

Comment: @grm: if the school's mail only supports pop, why do you need IMAP support?

Comment: @Senseful sorry, type. Only supports IMAP it should have been.

Comment: @grm: I updated the question to hopefully make it clearer. From what I understand, this is about reading an IMAP email address via Gmail's interface, and not importing (which usually means a one-time thing).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're going to have to work around this a little bit yourself. What you will need is a daemon or frequently run job that fires off something like [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) which is configured to login to your imap account, suck off your mail and either forward it to your gmail address or manually deliver it into another imap account (again, your gmail box).

This will need to run from somewhere consistently in order for you to have your mail up to date, but it doesn't have to be the box you check your mail from. You will be able to use your gmail from anywhere as usual as long as that fetchmail or similar is running somewhere acting as that little tunnel porting mail from one place to the other.

Comment: as of 2015, the feature is still not in gmail

Comment: As of 2017, the feature is still not in Gmail. (But it's there in the Gmail Android app :/)

Comment: @JohnRed, what happens when you set that up in the Android app? Does it actually solve the whole problem, regularly importing that IMAP email into your Gmail inbox?

Comment: It does. (I haven't configured it myself, but I have friends at work who do, and I haven't heard them complaining.)

Comment: @JohnRed Are you sure the mails get uploaded also to the web version of Gmail or are they only in the android phone?

Comment: @sup You can't access the web version. You cannot use your Gmail in your browser for an IMAP email account. You have to use the app.

Comment: @JohnRed that does not make much sense. Lots of clients can access multiple accounts via IMAP. What the OP wants is to get to mails on non-gmail account via IMAP and via Gmail at the same time.

Comment: 2018, June, the feature is still not there in Gmail. Come on, folks at Google, we need this! :/

Comment: As of 2019, guess what... still not there.

Comment: As of October 2019, and my institution is going to kill off POP3 protocol, leaving IMAP the only protocol to access email, Gmail still only allows POP...

Comment: As 2020, still not in Gmail, meanwhile we almost perfected the driverless cars and very close to curing cancer.

Comment: As 2021, you still can't use IMAP to access emails on Gmail.

Comment: 2022 says hi – still no IMAP support. We can probably conclude that this is excluded from their roadmap.

Comment: 2023 still no IMAP!!! Urra!

Comment: Just FTR (and to predict that it's not gonna happen in 2024 either): since GMail is not a free universal email client, but a frontend to GMail mailboxes specifically, and Google is into maximizing mail data stored on their servers, it would be counterproductive for them to actively support using other mailboxes elsewhere with their client _without importing_ (which is the whole point of IMAP, as opposed to POP3).

Comment: The date is November 11, 2023. Humans live in the shadow of AI, anxiously anticipating it replacing jobs everywhere. Smartphones, once the pinnacle of technology, now face their imminent decline, outpaced by brain-implanted chips and AI companion gadgets equipped with laser-projected screens. Financial systems tremble at the prospect of being supplanted by crypto alternatives, threatening to wrest monetary control from governments. On the streets, self-driving cars with aesthetics reminiscent of 'Blade Runner' are now a reality...

But Gmail... Oh, Gmail... DOESN'T SUPPORT IMAP!

Comment: I have opened a thread requesting IMAP support in Google Support, please vote here https://support.google.com/mail/thread/257337802?hl=en&sjid=17900848034006275474-SA

Answer (score 2):

You can use a browser plugin (with GreaseMonley) to fetch pop3 email every 8 minutes.

See http://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/gmail-pop3-checker-for-greasemonkey/#install

Comment: He looks for a solution that addresses IMAP not POP3.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to dump a lot of mail into gmail initially, there are a lot of tools out there to help with that.

One approach:

1. open up an email client like Thunderbird
2. add both gmail and your other account as IMAP accounts
3. drag and drop all the mail from your other account into gmail

Of course if you really want this to happen continuously, pop3 is your only option right now. Many imap providers also support pop3, though, so you could consider that.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[this site](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/) has an imapcopy tool that you'd have to setup to run on your own server somewhere.  Otherwise all you can do is go to [Suggest a Feature](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs) and go down to "I have another idea" to submit a request.

Comment: As of 2013, this highly desirable feature is still not available in GMail.
:( I know that is not the answer you wanted to hear. ): @Brad_Mace, oddly, when I go to Google's Feature Suggestion page via your link, there is no "I have another idea" link. Hmm. As if they are tired of hearing about potential improvements.

Comment: As of sept 2016, still here... I doubt it will be ever implemented, it would have been already done..