# Can I set up Gmail to fetch messages from another IMAP account?

Tags: gmail, imap

I have my work webmail that only offers IMAP access, no forwarding. I want to fetch it using Gmail, which, I already know, doesn't support fetching mail from IMAP accounts. Only POP3.

I've read other questions here with no useful responses, or proposed solutions that involve having a server working in a computer of my own, but I want to find an entirely internet-based solution.

I found that Outlook.com has both "imap importing" and POP3 access, and successfully imported the old mail from my work account to Gmail using Outlook as intermediary, but in Outlook, the IMAP fetching seems to be a one-time-only import thing, i.e., it doesn't automatically fetch more mails as they arrive.

So do you know of another way to get the e-mails from my IMAP-only work webmail into Gmail as they arrive?

Comment: The best way to get a more up-to-date answer on the other question is to put a bounty on it (when you have more than 75 reputation) and specify your requirements as you've done here.

Answer (score 10):

Gmail does not natively support reading imap based emails so you will need to use an intermediary solution. In this case I suggest following the answer on a related question:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/7629/14954

Good luck!